# Python append() removes utf-8 encoding?

Tags: python, html, xml, encoding, utf-8

** update: I tried saving the final list to a csv file and there saw everything looks fine. As Alex H. has mentioned below in his answer, print results of list (strings) dont always look pretty.

I am a newbie just getting started with web data analysis using python. It is frustrating to run into this problem and I hope sincerely someone can help me out!

I am trying to work with scraped text data from website. Below are my codes (plz note I just randomly picked a website to test with its about-us info). I want the final ps list to include just three blocks of text encoded as utf-8. However, when I print each block of text encoded individually results look fine (all html format is removed) but when I print ps, the final appended list, html format was still there. Does append() function remove encoding results? if so, what can I do to preserve encoding for the ps list?

```
import urllib2
def download(url, user_agent='wswp', num_retries=2):
    print 'downloading: ', url
    headers={'User-agent': user_agent}
    request=urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
    opener=urllib2.build_opener()
    try:
        html=opener.open(request).read()
    except urllib2.URLError as e:
        print 'Download error: ', e.reason
        html=None
        if num_retries>0:
            if hasattr(e, 'code') and 500<=e.code<600:
                return download(url, user_agent, num_retries-1)
    return html

url='http://www.piqproducts.com/pages/who-we-are'
html=download(url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
ps = []
for p in soup.findAll('p'):
    x=p.text.encode("utf-8")
    print x
    ps.append(x)
print ps
for p in soup.findAll('p'):
    print p.text.encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: The line `print p.text.encode("utf-8")` throws an error because the elements of `ps` are already strings. It seems to me that your code already does what you want it to.

Comment: I made corrections to the code. Now if you rerun it, you will see "print ps" will print unclean format but "print p.text.encode("utf-8") will print clean text.

Comment: since I appended text to ps after encoding is done, I don't understand why when I print ps it is still not the encoded results.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real problem here, just don't expect to see things looking pretty when you print the list. You shouldn't need to print the list for any real purposes anyway, you can get whatever output you want by handling the items individually. Lists have their own string representation. Here's a console session which might explain a bit.

```
>>> ps = ['a', 'b', 'ç']
>>> print ps
['a', 'b', '\xc3\xa7']
>>> for p in ps: print p
... 
a
b
ç
>>> print ps[2]
ç
>>> print repr(ps[2])
'\xc3\xa7'
>>> repr(ps) == str(ps)
True
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I did try to save the ps results to a csv file and there everything looks clean.

Comment: I will upvote your answer if I could but my reputation is too low... :( thanks again for the help